# User controls do not properly fit on the screen

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, dock

My application has several controls. Like in one screen has TreeView on left side, GridView with paging in the middle and 4 buttons at right side. The controls properly appear when the form is in a maximized state, but if I minimize it the controls do not properly fit on the screen.

I tried with different different tricks like table layout.. in dat I added a panel, etc...

But I could not solve the problem.

How can I create such type of screens which fits independently of size of my window?

Thanks

Comment: What are the anchor points for each control? You might find that you need to set the correct anchor points.

Comment: anchor points for Tree View is left-bottom, gridview - left-right-bottom, and for button panel - rigth-bottom..

Comment: How do you expect controls to be visible or fit a minimized window?

Comment: Like most are standard softwares are having this capability.

Comment: I think you need to define more clearly "do not properly fit on the screen." Is something getting cut off? What? The question title refers to dock.Full, but the question body doesn't mention it.

Comment: This question needs to be completely reworded with more detail added.  Also, please define your use of "minimize" and "screen".  You seem to be misusing them both.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a while ago. In my case i had a Button and a ListView within a GroupBox that was inside a SplitContainer, which was within a UserControl on a TabControl. I wanted the button on the top right located and anchored and the ListView took the space leftover, so i couldn't dock it. Instead it was anchored in all four places.

In my case my button and the listview are worked and behaved correctly in the designer, but in my running app the button was positioned to far on the right and the ListView size had also a too much width.

For a first bugfix i did some iterations about positioning the button in the designer a little more to the left, check it running mode, re-align the button in designer from the impression i had in the last run.

So i got it to work and started over with some other thing i had to do in my app. After a while i got a new feature request and needed another button within this messy thing. This time i did a complete rebuild of the gui elements on a new usercontrol, just to see if the problem reappears. To my amazement this gui mock just behaved as expected.

Within my code i didn't anything about changing the location, size, anchors, docks, etc. So the problem had to be within the `InitializeComponents()` code created by the designer.

I started with a diff of both versions and couldn't see any big differences (there were a lot of them, but only minors like size, location or name). So i started to put code from my crazy usercontrol into the mock and running the mock in my app. After several copies the problem also appears in my mock, so i got the root cause of the problem.

What do you think, which property leaded to the crazy behaviour?
It was the **MinimumSize** of my **SplitContainer**!

So to get really the root cause of your problem you should start over with an empty UserControl (or Form) and just place all the elements on it with the desired behaviour (size, location, anchor, dock).

Nothing more!

Then test if this mock behaves the way you want and if not, post this code here and tell us what you expected to see.